# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class JEditor

Tags: joomla-3.x, fatal-error

This is the first time I get this error.

This ocurred after creating a new custom module, which comes with joomla by default.

After that, I got blank page and the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class JEditor in \\WAGNER\WWWROOTAMENPT$\xxxxxx.hostnd\htdocs\www\libraries\cms\editor\editor.php on line 554
```

It seems that it happens after trying to create this custom module, but I already deleted and it's still showing up.

I haven't installed any new extention and everything was working fine, until I created this custom module.

Joomla 3.5.0

Best regards

Comment: What version of Joomla?

Comment: @Lodder Joomla 3.5.0, updated.
Ok, so it seems that after deleting this module created, it no longer displays the error. But it's odd, since this module is from Joomla package... I've used it before and never had troubles.

Comment: Not sure but you should always stay updated as patches will fix bugs

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is another place that you have the class "JEditor" defined.

If you have shell (ssh) access to your server, try running the below under your Joomla directory:

```
grep -R --include=*.php "class JEditor"
```

You should only see one file (which is the `/libraries/cms/editor/editor.php` file). If you see 2 files then  your problem is with the second file (it might be loaded by a plugin).

If you only found one file, then check your plugins for any plugin that you installed lately and disable that plugin (disable plugins one by one in a reverse chronological order).

Note: Make sure you delete your Joomla cache.